# CSS and JS do not work properly in Laravel 5

Tags: php, css, laravel-5

I am new at Laravel 5 and I have some problems with css and js. I have url which is defined in routes.php like following:

```
Route::get('/search/{category}', function($category){
$products = DB::select('select * from product where category = ?', [$category]);
if($products) {
    return view('search', compact('products'));
}else{
    return view('errors.404');
}
```

});

And my link to page in html is like:

```
<li><a href="{{URL::to("/")}}/search/woman" title="">WOMENSWEAR</a></li>
<li><a href="{{URL::to("/")}}/search/man" title="">MENSWEAR</a></li>
<li><a href="{{URL::to("/")}}/search/kid" title="">KIDSWEAR</a></li>
```

When I go to '/search' page it works well. But when category added to the end of url css and js is not work properly. How can I solve it?

Comment: How are you calling the CSS and JS?

Comment: I have layout.blade.php page. And search.blade.php extends it. And all my CSS and JS file are called in layout file like this: '<link rel="stylesheet" href="stylex/css/style.css" type="text/css">'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Laravel looks in your public folder for assets, so place your css folder into **public** Directory.Each of your href's should start with a slash

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/style.css">
```

so that it is looking in the right place. If you don't include that slash it looks in a path relative to itself instead of in the public folder. Also, make sure that your assets are indeed in your public folder.